# cant able to get selected option from OptionDialog box in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have created a OptionDialog in Titanium. I have added those option list from a dynamic array. how to get the particular option value on clicking any item from dialog box?

```
var View = Ti.UI.createTextField({
height : '60dp',
width : '90%',
value : 'click here'
)};

myArray = ['Lion','Tiger','Cat','Elephant','Dog'];

var opts = {
  cancel: 2,
  options: myArray,
  selectedIndex: 2,
  destructive: 0,
};

var dialog;
View.addEventListener('click',function(){
    dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog(opts).show();
});
```

I have tried like below,which doesn't work.

```
dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    alert('You Clicked' + e.source.options);
});
```

Comment: which os you're using? Android or ios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
var myArray = ['Lion','Tiger','Cat','Elephant','Dog'];

var opts = {
  cancel: 2,
  options: myArray,
  selectedIndex: 2,
  destructive: 0,
};

var dialog;
View.addEventListener('click',function(){
    dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog(opts);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.addEventListener('click', onSelectDialog);
});

function onSelectDialog(event){
    var selectedIndex = event.source.selectedIndex;
    //OR
    //var selectedIndex = dialog.selectedIndex();
    alert('You have selected' + myArray[selectedIndex ]);
}
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: //OR
    //var selectedIndex = dialog.getSelectedIndex();

Comment: you can use either of it. That's why I added it there.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog event listener [passes the *index* into](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.OptionDialog-event-click) the supplied options array (`myArray` in your case) that was selected, not the option itself.

Try this instead assuming you have your array defined:

```
var myArray = ['Lion','Tiger','Cat','Elephant','Dog'];

....

dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    alert('You Clicked' + myArray[e.index]);
});
```

This will alert the option from `myArray` that was chosen.

Comment: i have tried above code. But following line throws error as: "dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){" not defined

Comment: Did you instantiate the dialog before you add the listener.

Comment: yeah.i have declared it properly outside View's click event.